# react-router-redux webpack dev server historyApiFallback fails

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, webpack-dev-server, react-router-redux

After enabling historyApiFallback in the webpack config file and restarting the server, when changing location pathname, the browser refreshes, causing outer elements to re-mount (what I mean is that, I can see it flash white and back to normal) where this should only happen for nested `the.props.children`.

In my particular case, there's a `<Navbar />` element that is always present at the top and a container that has the `{ this.props.children }`. I wonder what's going on?

App entrypoint:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);
// const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <Router history={ history } routes={ routes } />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

webpack config file:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        './src/js/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/static',
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ["react-hot-loader", "babel-loader"] },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass' },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: __dirname + '/src/' + 'index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname),
        extensions: ['', '.js'],
        alias: {
            "TweenLite": "src/libs/gsap/TweenLite",
            "CSSPlugin": "src/libs/gsap/plugins/CSSPlugin"
        }
    }
};
```

main wrapper/container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../containers/navbar';
import ModalWindow from '../components/modalWindow';

// include the stylesheet entry point
require('../../sass/app.scss');

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Navbar />
                <main>
                { this.props.children }
                </main>
                <ModalWindow />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

router config file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './containers/app';
import InitialScreen from './containers/initialScreen';
import Reservation from './containers/reservation';

const routes = (
    <Route path='/' component={ App }>
        <IndexRoute component={ InitialScreen } />
        <Route path='your-trolley' component={ Reservation } />           
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

So far, I think there's something wrong in the webpack dev config file.

### Update

Random user asked how the location is changed, so here's the action:

```
export function fetchReservationData(reservation_code, onError) {

    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(apiConfig.find_my_product)
            .then(function(response) {

                if (response.ok) {

                    response.json().then(function (data) {
                        if (data.trolley.length > 0) {
                            dispatch({ type: UPDATE_TROLLEY_DATA, payload: data });
                            // todo: use router-redux push instead
                            window.location.pathname = '/your-trolley';

                        } else {
                            dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_MODAL_WINDOW, payload: onError });                          
                        }
                    });

                } else {

                    // todo: handle exception
                    console.log('Network response was not ok.');
                    dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_MODAL_WINDOW, payload: onError });

                }

            })
            .catch(function (error) {

                // todo: handle error
                // handle it gracefully asked user to try again, if the problem keeps ocurring to
                // talk with a staff member to report it to the backend team
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
                dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_MODAL_WINDOW, payload: onError });

            });
    }

}
```

Here's where the problem is; If I change the app entry point it works:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);
// const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(browserHistory))
);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

setTimeout(() => {
    store.dispatch(push('/your-trolley'));
}, 3000);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <Router history={ history } routes={ routes } />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

So now I'll need to be able to dispatch the push from the action as I did in the entry point. It's a bit confusing because I'm pasing a middleware to the store and then the store is sync with the browserhistory, I guess I'll need to pass the return value from applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(browserHistory)) in both cases (createstore and sunchistorywithstore)?

Comment: I dont know much about `historyApiFallback` but you can try removing `/` from `Route path='/your-trolley'` .. it looks like `Route path='your-trolley'` and see it that helps.

Comment: Thanks for looking! I tried that but unfortunately it's not working still.

Comment: Are you using `a` or `Link from react-router` to change between pages? How do you change `location path`?

Comment: I was doing it by changing the window.location.pathname, tried to set a timeout in the app entry point, after applying a routerMiddleWare and it works fine! Thank you! I'll try to figure out how to modify the syncHistoryWithStore with this.

Comment: What you could do is `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';` and in your timeout, call `browserHistory.push('/path/to/url);` instead of `window.location.pathname`

Comment: Yes, that works fine! Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it ? can be useful in the future for someone else. I did find this documentation and it mentions to use the store dispatch event with the push call as an argument ( https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions ) but no idea how to access store from actions. Your solution is working though and I'm cool with it!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `react-router` and don't want the browser to reload the entire page everytime you switch to new url, It's important to use the **`<Link>`** component provided by `react-router` or create your own version of the component.

To link between different pages you can

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
```

And then you it in your `render` function, use it like

```
<Link to="/user/profile">Goto Profile Page</Link>
<Link to="/">Homepage</Link>
```

And if you want to **programmatically redirect** user to different url/location

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

let doSomething = () => {
  // do something
  browserHistory.push('/user/profile');
}
```

---

#### **Edit:** If you want to Redirect using `push` method provided by `react-router-redux`, You can do something like this

```
// import push from react-router-redux
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

// when props.redirect is called, dispatch the push method
const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch, ownProps ) => {
  return {
    goto: (path) => dispatch( push(path) ),
  }
}


let Component = (props) => {

  // when called, this will call goto on props which inturn will dispatch the `push` method.
  let gotoNewPage = () => {
    props.goto('/some/page');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <button onClick={ gotoNewPage }>Goto New Page</button>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: It's react-router-redux though